# Visual Studio 2012 Web config?

Tags: visual-studio

I just switched over from Visual Web Developer to Visual studio 2012, I am a very novice asp.net programmer and know little to nothing about what a web config file's contents should contain / mean. I noticed the web configs file is drastically less populated by default in visual web studio, does this mean i have to hand code everything that used to be automatically populated? Or is there a way to get the necessities (for example the necessary login code) auto populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add contents to web.config based on your requirement.

Less contents gives us cleaner web.config and only required things are there.